# RTL support on Sencha Touch and JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, sencha-touch, mobile-website, right-to-left

I want to develop a mobile application site, and after a lot of searching I found the best two frameworks to develop in are:

- 1) Sencha Touch
- 2) JQuery Mobile

  didn't choose one of them yet, but I think I will go with Sencha Touch.

**My question is:**

are these two frameworks support RTL, I want to write my application in both English and Arabic, and to work for `iOS,Android,BlackBerry,Symbian and Windows`.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

All of the alignments in both projects are made through CSS.
You need to alter the CSS values according to the language you are using.

The main things you should notice are:

```
direction:ltr / direction:rtl

float:left / float: right

text-align: left / text-align: right
```

Try switching the values between them and that should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch does not support RTL in its prebuilt widgets, but will *eventually* and it does not yet support Windows Phone. Symbian is not on our roadmap.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still wants an RTL jQuery Mobile I made the changes to the JavaScript and Themes for both 1.0.1 and 1.1.0 RC versions here: http://www.intlaqa.com/jquery-mobile-rtl/